# Strapi - Filtering a relationship field with conditions

Tags: strapi

I have 3 collections: workouts (w), categories (c), and category_groups (cg).

The relationships are as follows:

- (w) belongsToOne (c)
- (c) belongsToOne (cg)

When adding a new workout, I want to display only (cg) belonging to the (c) which I selected previously instead of showing all the (cg).

Here is an image to help you visualize more easily.

[image]

Comment: That’s not available by default, you need custom field for that, inspiration https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-categorizer